# Showing content of all textfiles in folder into a textbox VB

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I need to show the content of multiple textfiles in the same folder in a textbox.

My code right now:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim dMods1 = "DirectPathToFolderWithTextFiles"
    Dim dMods2 = "DirectPathToFolderWithTextFiles"
    Dim dMods3 = "DirectPathToFolderWithTextFiles"
    Dim dMods4 = "DirectPathToFolderWithTextFiles"

    Dim fileCount1 As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(dMods1).Length
    Dim fileCount2 As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(dMods2).Length
    Dim fileCount3 As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(dMods3).Length
    Dim fileCount4 As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(dMods4).Length

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim nl = System.Environment.NewLine
        Dim Item = dMods1 & "\*.txt"
        Dim Item2 = dMods1 & "\sada2.txt"
        If Not Item Is Nothing Then

            TextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(Item)


        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

A simple "*.txt", like in "Item", gets the error "invalid characters in the path". How can i show the contents in the textbox? Or is there an easier way of doing it?

Comment: use `Path.Combine()` to create qualified paths.  There are no files or folders with a `*` in them though.  You may be mixing searching with opening files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for each loop on the files in the folder

```
        For Each FilePath As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Windows")
            If FilePath.ToLower.EndsWith(".txt") Then 
                TextBox1.text &= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Ill look into it. Ive got no clue on how for each loops works

Comment: made an example for you.

Comment: You can also use [`Directory.GetFiles("C:\Windows", "*.txt")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all `.txt` files in given path.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Wouldnt that just show the names of the files? Because i need the content of all the files

Comment: @Thomsen1707 myekem's answer is correct. I just shared a way to get `.txt` files from a path. The rest is the same as myekem's answer (without if statement). +1 to him

Comment: @Thomsen1707 By the way, when a post answers your question, you can click on check mark near the answer to mark it as [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647). It's also reasonable to click on up arrow near the answer to vote for it and say the answer is useful.

Comment: Thanks Reza for the tip, I'm no pro at programming so I am still learning as well.